# How to create a navigation li click event to add/remove class on a Sub Menu ul li

Tags: jquery, navigation

I am adapting a wordpress menu so that I can create my own navigation, but have come unstuck on displaying my submenu on mobile devices.  You can see on this JSfiddle, that when you hover over the main menu item, it shows the sub menu but its not working of course on mobile devices.

The structure of the menu is

```
<ul class="navigation__list">
 <li class="navigation__link"><a>Main Menu Item</a>
  <ul class="navigation_item--submenu">
   <li class="navigation__link"><a>Sub Menu Item</a>
   <li class="navigation__link"><a>Sub Menu Item</a>
   <li class="navigation__link"><a>Sub Menu Item</a>
   <li class="navigation__link"><a>Sub Menu Item</a>
  </ul>
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/42pmqyL5/2/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery(".navigation__list li ").click(function () {
  if(jQuery(".navigation__link ul li").hasClass('show-menu')){
    jQuery(".navigation__link ul li").removeClass('show-menu')
  }else{
    jQuery(".navigation__link ul li").addClass('show-menu');
  }
 });
});
```

What I want to achieve is that on navigation__list li click, that its related ul li shows up, but I really am lost on how to achieve this as the jsfiddle I tried isnt working.

Any help would be much appreciated on how to structure the jquery so it does what I want.

Many thanks

Comment: Jquery events for mobile devices use a different api: [jQuery Mobile](https://jquerymobile.com/)

Comment: So does my code look ok? its just the version of jquery I am using???

Comment: No it's wrong for mobile devices with a touchscreen, different events, there is no `click` event. I believe it's a `touch` event.  You'll have to do some research